# Python regex problem to convert python3.8 class to python3.7

Tags: python, regex, algorithm

In python3.8 we can directly give the function variable data type while defining the function itself. But this does not work for all versions of python and gives syntax error. I was attempting to using python `re` module to convert the code from one format to another.

## Given String

```
a = """\
class Solution:
    def minCostClimbingStairs(self, c: List[int]) -> int:
        '''There may or maynot be this docstring.

        '''
        c1, c2 = c[0], c[1]
        for i in range(2,len(c)): c1, c2 = c2, c[i] + min(c1,c2)
        return min(c1, c2)
"""
```

## Required output

```
ans = '''\
class Solution:
    def minCostClimbingStairs(self, c):
        """
        There may or maynot be this docstring.
        :type c: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        c1, c2 = c[0], c[1]
        for i in range(2,len(c)): c1, c2 = c2, c[i] + min(c1,c2)
        return min(c1, c2)
'''
```

## My attempt

```py
import re

pat = r'(.*)(def.+self.*,)(->)\s*(\w+)\s*:' # this is just example, it does not work
parts = re.findall(pat,a)

Once I find the parts, then I need to change them and will make it like answer part.
```

## Question

How to get strings parts

```
part1: (it can have self or not)
----------------------------------
class Solution:
    def minCostClimbingStairs(self,

part2: function arguments
----------------------------
c

part3: output type
------------------
int

part4: docstring if is present
--------------------------------
There may or maynot be this docstring.

part5: All the actual code inside the function
------------------------------------------------
        c1, c2 = c[0], c[1]
        for i in range(2,len(c)): c1, c2 = c2, c[i] + min(c1,c2)
        return min(c1, c2)
```

Comment: If source file have a syntax valid, you can try `exec()` them and getting function signature by [inspect.Signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature) method.

Comment: @StanislavIvanov That's an incredible info to know, but the class Solution is Invalid syntax in python3.7. (it gives NameError List) so unfortunately I can not use `inspect` module. I need to parse the individual components and re-format them.

Comment: Regexes are the wrong solution to this; you should transform the abstract syntax tree. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks a lot, but first I need to parse the string. The class above is not a valid syntax. its just a string for python 3.7 so i need to parse part by part. I am looking simple wayaround to get some parts, not state of the art parser.

Comment: the title seems wrong, python 3.7 supports type hints

Comment: Even Python 3.5 supports them. https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/typing.html The string `a` can be parsed just fine by `ast.parse` in Python 3.5 and later, with no syntax errors. What could be simpler than that? https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks a lot kaya. This solves the problem. I will do few edits and make the required changes. Thanks a lot.